# How to improve a long if-else chain?

Tags: java

EDIT: I think that the if-statement might go in the main class, I still am not sure how to do it.

I have this project, i have serialized an arrayList and then deserialized it.

Now i am stuck on how to go through it and get certain values.

Code is below:

```
        grade =  deserStudents.getGrade();
        firstName = deserStudents.getFirstName();
        lastName = deserStudents.getLastName();         

        if(grade > 0 && grade < 1) {
            letterGrade = "F";
        }

        else if(grade >= 1 && grade < 2) {
            letterGrade = "D";
        }

        else if(grade >= 2 && grade < 2.3) {
            letterGrade = "C";
        }               

        else if(grade >= 2.3 && grade < 2.7) {
            letterGrade = "C+";
        }

        else if(grade >= 2.7 && grade < 3) {
            letterGrade = "B-";
        }

        else if(grade > 3 && grade < 3.3) {
            letterGrade = "B";
        }

        else if(grade >= 3.3 && grade < 3.7) {
            letterGrade = "B+";
        }

        else if(grade >= 3.7 && grade < 4) {
            letterGrade = "A";
        }

        else if(grade > 4 && grade <= 4.3) {
            letterGrade = "A+";
        }
        else {
            assert false : " Invalid grade " + grade;
        }

        System.out.println("- " +firstName+ " - " + lastName+ " - " + grade + " - " + letterGrade);
```

As you can see in the DeSerielizationHelper the way i am supposed to do this is a huge if/else statement. I just cant seem to find a way to extract the grade's,names of the deserStudents. Anyone know a fix?

Thanks

Comment: Neither Serialization nor ArrayList has anything to do with the actual question.

Comment: You don't need to paste the entire code of your project, just the relevant parts. In this case, your if-else chain would be enough

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the double condition on your `if`s.

```
    if(grade < 0) {
        assert false : " Invalid grade " + grade;
    }
    else if(grade < 1) {
        letterGrade = "F";
    }
    else if(grade < 2) {     // we already know grade >= 1
        letterGrade = "D";
    }
    else if(grade < 2.3) {   // we already know grade >= 2
        letterGrade = "C";
    }
```

Other than this, the other thing you can do is to create an array with your thresholds and the corresponding values. Then use a `for` loop to iterate through them and perform the `if`conditions.

```
// X stands for invalid (when grade is below 0 or above 4.3
double [] values = {0, 1, 2, 2.3};        // etc etc
String [] grades = {"X", "F", "D", "C"};  // etc etc
letterGrade == "X";                       // Set it to invalid in case it's above 4.3

for(int i=0; i<values.length; i++){
    if(grade<values[i]){ 
        letterGrade=grades[i]; 
        break; 
    }
}

// if invalid, throw error
if("X".equals(letterGrade)) 
    assert false : " Invalid grade " + grade;
```